# Where can I find a rich dataset for testing visualization software?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visualization

I am developing a ASP.Net data visualization web application similar to google analytics and I need a rich dataset to test it with. The application allows data visualization by state and over time.

I am having trouble finding a rich dataset and do not know who to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find something useful [here](http://www.destatis.de), which is what I do, when I need sample data. It's the website of the german ministry of statistics. For example this [link](http://www.destatis.de/jetspeed/portal/cms/Sites/destatis/Internet/DE/Content/Statistiken/Zeitreihen/WirtschaftAktuell/Basisdaten/Content100/vpi001a.psml) shows the increase in price for consumer goods since '05.

Answer (score 0):

How about Microsoft's Northwind or AdventureWorks sample databases ?
More samples [here](http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=30803)